# How do I change the default corner of the Desktop?

Tags: macos, desktop

I'm using Mac OSX 10.6.8 and when I save things to the desktop, drop something there in Finder or take a screengrab with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>/<kbd>4</kbd>, it gets placed in the top-right corner.

I tend to position my windows in a bottom-left to top-right diagonal fashion, meaning the top-right corner of the desktop is always covered, as such I'd rather that new things placed on the desktop appeared in the top-left, where there's a gap and I can get to them easily.

Is it possible to adjust the "default" corner items are placed in on the Desktop?
And if so, how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.  I can think of a couple work arounds though...

Don't auto arrange and keep a folder in the bottom left.  Make it your default download location.  (poor workaround I'll admit)

or

Do use auto arrange and fill up a good chunk of the desktop with invisible (transparent) alias icons, so that new icons naturally fill in towards the left side of the desktop.

Neither is ideal, but may alleviate the top-right-always-covered issue.